# With ESLint running in SublimeLinter, is it possible to change the colors for warnings/errors from different plugins?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, eslint, sublimelinter

I'm using a variety of ESLint plugins to develop my application, and it would be immensely useful for me to get SublimeLinter to display a different color for warnings/errors coming from particular plugins. Does anybody know if this is possible?